# Protocol: Coin Flipping over phone

Tags: entropy

**Protocol:** Coin Flipping over telephone

**Hypothesis:**

Alice and Bob have agreed:

1. a one to one function $f$ which is easy to compute $f(x)$ from $x$ and while given any value $f(x)$ it is nearly impossible to find any information about $x$.
2. an even number $x$ in $f(x)$ represent HEAD and the other case represents TAILS.

**STEP:**

1. Alice picks a large random integer $x$ and compute $f(x)$; she reads $f(x)$ to Bob over the phone;
2. Bob tells Alice his guess of $x$ as even or odd;
3. Alice read $x$ to Bob;
4. Bob verifies $f(x)$ and sees the correctness or incorrectness of his guess.

**Objectives:**

1. Calculate the uncertainty of Alice.
2. Let $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Can $f(x)=x^2\mod{n}$ be used in protocol above? Please give your reason to support your answer.

---

**My try:**

1. Alice is sender. Plain-text, $x\in P$
   Bob is receiver. Cipher-text, $C$
   $f(x)$ is encryption function.

   $\therefore$ The uncertainty of Alice is $H(P)=-\sum_{x\in P}Pr(x) \log_2{Pr(x)}$?
2. Yes, because it is one to one function?

Am I correct? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: It's not a one-to-one function, though - not even if $n$ is prime. You can see that it maps both $x$ and $-x$ to the same output value, so its range is at most half its domain (exactly half, if $n$ is prime - otherwise, quite a bit less depending on $p$ and $q$).

Comment: So, it is my 1st question correct? And the reason for 2nd question is just only it is not one to one function?

Comment: What is "uncertainty" in this context? And to 2: No it is wrong. The function is not binding at all, even without knowledge of $n$.

Comment: To (hopefully) clarify the above two comments, if you choose an even $x$, $-x = n-x$ is odd, so you could "reveal" either an odd or an even number. I don't think one-to-one is needed for a decent $f$, just preimage and second preimage resistance, which $x^2 \bmod n$ lacks.

Comment: Since this looks like a homework question, I didn't want to spoil the answer right away. Even preimage resistance isn't needed, it just has to be a binding commitment scheme. Of course, preimage resistance provides some computational binding scheme.